# Server calls some, but not all, client-side methods

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, signalr

I have a pretty basic SignalR configuration setup with my ASP.NET website.  I can make calls to the server and invoke *some* methods on all connected clients.  But other methods don't seem to work and I get the following error.

> 500: 'XXX' method could not be resolved.

I thought it was maybe conflicting method names between the server and client, but I struggle to believe that.  One thing to note is that it does fail for methods that invoke client-side methods that take an argument.  Here's my code:

**Server Side**

```
<HubName("myHub")>
    Public Class myHub
    Inherits Hub

    Public Sub sendMsg(ByVal message As String, ByVal Optional target As String = "")
        Clients.All.invoke_message(Context.ConnectionId, message)
    End Sub

    Public Sub refresh()
        Clients.All.invoke_refresh()
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Client Side**

```
window.myHub = $.connection.myHub;

myHub.client.invoke_refresh = function () {
    // invoked to force the user's page to refresh
    document.location.reload(true);
}

myHub.client.invoke_message = function (clientID, message) {
    // invoked while broadcasting a message
    console.log(clientID + ': ' + message);
};
```

The refresh method works fine.  The new message returns the above error.

Any thoughts?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feels a little bit silly.  SignalR, in an upgrade, broke the ability to handle server-side methods that take an optional parameter and are called without passing those optional parameters.  [See the issue here](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/324).

As a note to anyone upgrading from ~v0.53 to v1.0, this is something to watch out for.

Answer (score 1):

In SignalR the server has no knowledge of any JS client side functions.  It only sends messages down to the client and the client invokes the given function if it exists.

Therefore the fact that you're seeing a 500 error (Internal Server Error) leads me to believe it has nothing to with the client.

That being said I went ahead and tested out your code in C# and it worked fine.  Also made a VB.Net project and finally got it to work properly.

Here's the code for my VB.Net project:

**Server Hub (MyHub.vb)**

```
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs

<HubName("myHub")>
Public Class MyHub
    Inherits Hub

    Public Sub sendMsg(ByVal message As String)
        Clients.All.invoke_message(Context.ConnectionId, message)
    End Sub

    Public Sub refresh()
        Clients.All.invoke_refresh()
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Client Side code (default.aspx):**

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="default.aspx.vb" Inherits="VBTest._default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <div id="SendMessage">SendMsg</div>
        <div id="Refresh">Refresh</div>
    </div>
    </form>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.0.0-rc1.js"></script>
    <script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.myHub = $.connection.myHub;

        myHub.client.invoke_refresh = function () {
            // invoked to force the user's page to refresh
            document.location.reload(true);
        }

        myHub.client.invoke_message = function (clientID, message) {
            // invoked while broadcasting a message
            console.log(clientID + ': ' + message);
        };

        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $("#SendMessage").click(function () {
                window.myHub.server.sendMsg("ELLO");
            });

            $("#Refresh").click(function () {
                window.myHub.server.refresh();
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Global.asax:**

```
Imports System.Web.SessionState
Imports System.Web.Routing
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR

Public Class Global_asax
    Inherits System.Web.HttpApplication

    Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs()
    End Sub
End Class
```

And a SS of my folder structure:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeljM.jpg

Make sure you remove the App_Start code and replace it with the Global.asax code.

One thing that I did do differently is I grabbed all my SignalR code from the source (https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/tree/release).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great explanation.  Ultimately, the problem was with an optional parameter passed in one of my server-side methods.  I had dumbed down my code when I originally posted -- see my edit for the optional parameter.  Anyhow -- it's a bug in the most recent version of SignalR and they're aware of it.  Thanks for a solid explanation though!